# Why can some Celery workers stop without any evidence of failure?

Tags: python, kubernetes, microservices, celery

I have an event-driven architecture in a part of my application that is implemented in Celery workers. It is a training of machine learning models so the process is usually somewhat delayed (around 48 hours). So at a certain point, there is a communication between workers that invoke each other's tasks and do some things.
The problem is that one of my workers in the middle of the process stopped out of nowhere... there is no error log, he was simply checking the kubernetes pod logs and the last thing was a simple:

```
sync with celery@thori-at-pronosticos-worker-forecast-model-training-deployhvhhl
```

Nothing more... no error log. (The worker still had pending tasks to do)
I'm very sorry that I don't have to give more context but there really isn't any. Any idea why this could happen with Celery? Anyone else has happened?

Comment: Difficult without more context. If your executed code does not explicitly log you might not even see successful task executions in the celery logs. Also the code that is actually executed might be the culprit (e.g. causing a deadlock / infinite loop / making http request without timeout specified / waiting for another task to finish on the same [possibly single-threaded] worker / ...). Do you have liveness and readiness probes on the worker pods?

Comment: I will have to review the code, I have run the flow locally without problem, I doubt there are deadlocks or infinite loops. For http request without timeout specified I'm not so sure... When I restart the pod it continues with the process correctly. Thank you very much for your ideas, I will give the code a review.

Comment: In that case, proper liveness and readiness probes should solve your problems as their failing will cause kubernetes to kill/restart the pod.

Answer (score 1):

You say "process stopped out of nowhere"... - This never happens, there is always a reason (IF that actually happened at all). Did you check whether the process is indeed not running, if so how (ps, pstree)? With the amount of information you gave us there is no way to determine what actually happened.

If the process is indeed dead, yet in the Celery log you have that "sync with..." line as the last one, that probably means that it got killed by the OOM killer (system killed it because it was taking all available RAM). One way to check whether this is really what happened is to go through the `dmesg` output (assuming the underlying OS is Linux)

Finally, did the worker execute any task at all? (You should be able to see that in the Celery log) - If it did not, yet you think it should check which queue is it subscribed to, and check to which queue you are sending those tasks you expected to be executed.